# Non Recordsource - Does not update with the row

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, continuous-forms

I have a form that i am using to input information into a table.

Table Definition:

```
Field0 - AutoNumber
Field1 - Text
Field2 - Number (Loose Referential Integrity)
Field3 - Number (Loose Referential Integrity)
```

Control - Record Source:

```
TextBox - Field1
ComboBox1 - `Unbound`
ComboBox2 - Field2
ComboBox3 - Field3
```

In regards to the Form:

```
New Record - ComboBox1 defines the selections available in ComboBox2
Edit/View Record - ComboBox1.Value is deduced by the ComboBox2.Value
```

Originally, this Form was designed with Single Form layout, but the end-user wanted more of a Continuous Form layout and now when i view the list of values, ComboBox1 is the same value acrossed all `Rows`.  I was originally using the `Form_Current` event to handle the backward's inheritence to derive the Value of ComboBox1 from ComboBox2.  This is not quite working like it originally did when it was a Single Form.

How do i migrate a Single-Form Form_Current methodology to a Continuous Form logic so that each row is evaluated as its own single entity?

Currently, if i go look at a single row, it evaulates ComboBox1 from ComboBox2 but it evaulates all of the rows in the Continuous Form not just the row i happen to currently be on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that keeps coming up. You cannot sensibly use unbound controls in a continuous form. There are various work-arounds, according to what you are doing. The best is usually leave the editing to a pop-out form.

Alternatives include setting a textbox to the bound value and just marking the comboboxes "edit such-and-such".

Comment: Yes and no. It depends on what you want to do and how you define work.

Comment: How would i define a continuous form so that i dont have to add another reference field to the table so it will work on a RBR level?

Comment: It depends. If I understand you, which is another story, you can use a query or you can DLookUp. If instant editing is important, you can work-around the display problem, because that is what it is.

Comment: The Form is to be for data-entry, and since i dont want to list ALL of the available records to be displayed in ComboBox2, i am using ComboBox1 as a reducer in the available options.

Comment: As I said, this is a display problem, you only need that the combo displays data relevant to the current record, however, it is disconcerting for the user to see the data in the other records vanish. Create a textbox that display a dlookup for the fields that are to be edited with the combo, rename the combo to "edit fieldX".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15672/discussion-between-remou-and-goldbishop)

Comment: I do not understand that comment.

Comment: re your chat comment. The example I posted used an sql string as the record source. I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: I was thinking of doing a all inclusive query that provides all ID's for the form.  Then if the end-user makes a change on the current record, how would i handle the update of information to the correct table.  Im trying to think outside of the box, your solution is simple and works, but i like to have more than one tool in my belt.