# Using cascading combo boxes in a datasheet subform

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

In Access 2010, I have tables `Task` and `Action` that have a many-to-many relationship through table `ActionTask`.  In the form for `Task`, I want to put a subform for all the `Action`s related to the current task through the `ActionTask` junction table.

This, in itself, I can do.

The trick is that `Action` is actually the bottom rank of a four-tier hierarchy of tables.
Each `Action` belongs to a `Goal`, each `Goal` belongs to a `Theme`, each `Theme` belongs to a `Strategy`.

Rather than just have a combo box listing all the available `Action`s, I'd like to use cascading combo boxes for the `Strategy`/`Theme`/`Goal`/`Action`.

This I can also do.

The problem is when I use this technique in a datasheet, if I select a given row, the selected row shows the proper `Strategy`/`Theme`/`Goal`/`Action`, but in all the other rows

- the `Action` is blank
- the `Strategy`/`Theme`/`Goal` is set to the current row's values, rather than that row's values

[image: selecting one row in datasheet view]
[image: selecting another row in datasheet view]

I've tried using the "Continuous Forms" view rather than the "Datasheet" view, but the result is pretty much the same.

[image: selecting one row in continuous forms view]
[image: selecting another row in continuous forms view]

I think I know why (the `Me.StrategyCombo = ...` stuff in my `Form_Current` callback), but I don't know another way to achieve that.

How can I make the subform display all the rows properly?

---

[Here's the Access file](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6-U1uFbN8Ckc05ocFdhTEhHQXM), but all the relevant details should be below.

```
Tables:
  Strategy   : (ID, Desc)
  Theme      : (ID, StrategyID, Desc)
  Goal       : (ID, ThemeID, Desc)
  Action     : (ID, GoalID, Desc)
  Task       : (ID, Desc, ...)
  ActionTask : (ActionID, TaskID)

Form Settings:

  [Forms]![Task]![ActionTaskSub]:
    Link Master Fields: ID
    Link Child Fields : TaskID

  [Forms]![Task]![ActionTaskSub].[Form]:
    On Current:
      Private Sub Form_Current()
          ' when the form loads a record, should reverse propegate
          ' action > goal > theme > strategy
          Dim goalID, themeID, strategyID

          ' figure out the goal, theme, and strategy that go with this action
          If (Me.ActionID) Then
            goalID = DLookup("[GoalID]", "Action", "[ID] = " & CStr(Me.ActionID))
            themeID = DLookup("[ThemeID]", "Goal", "[ID] = " & CStr(goalID))
            strategyID = DLookup("[StrategyID]", "Theme", "[ID] = " & CStr(themeID))
          End if

          ' populate the combo boxes and make the appropriate selections
          Me.StrategyCombo = strategyID
          Me.ThemeCombo.Requery
          Me.ThemeCombo = themeID
          Me.GoalCombo.Requery
          Me.GoalCombo = goalID
          Me.ActionCombo.Requery
          Me.ActionCombo = Me.ActionID
      End Sub

  [Forms]![Task]![ActionTaskSub].[Form]![StrategyCombo]:
    Row Source  : SELECT [Strategy].[ID], [Strategy].[Desc] FROM [Strategy];
    After Update:
      Private Sub StrategyCombo_AfterUpdate()
          Me.ThemeCombo = Null
          Me.ThemeCombo.Requery
          Call ThemeCombo_AfterUpdate
      End Sub

  [Forms]![Task]![ActionTaskSub].[Form]![ThemeCombo]:
    Row Source  : SELECT [Theme].[ID], [Theme].[Desc] FROM [Theme] WHERE 
                  [Theme].[StrategyID] = [Forms]![Task]![ActionTaskSub].[Form]![StrategyCombo];
    After Update:
      Private Sub ThemeCombo_AfterUpdate()
          Me.GoalCombo = Null
          Me.GoalCombo.Requery
          Call GoalCombo_AfterUpdate
      End Sub

  [Forms]![Task]![ActionTaskSub].[Form]![GoalCombo]:
    Row Source  : SELECT [Goal].[ID], [Goal].[Desc] FROM [Goal] WHERE 
                  [Goal].[ThemeID] = [Forms]![Task]![ActionTaskSub].[Form]![ThemeCombo];
    After Update:
      Private Sub GoalCombo_AfterUpdate()
          Me.ActionCombo = Null
          Me.ActionCombo.Requery
      End Sub

  [Forms]![Task]![ActionTaskSub].[Form]![ActionCombo]:
    Row Source  : SELECT [Action].[ID], [Action].[Desc] FROM [Action] WHERE 
                  [Action].[GoalID] = [Forms]![Task]![ActionTaskSub].[Form]![GoalCombo];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Any action applies to the subform current record but appears to affect all controls. There are various work-arounds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019124/change-control-source-only-selected-combo-box-in-continous-form/13019266#13019266 -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075067/non-recordsource-does-not-update-with-the-row/12075115#12075115 -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072265/how-to-filter-a-table-fields-listbox-by-the-current-record/13072322#13072322

Comment: These answers basically say the same thing, but make no sense.  How is it confusing for a user to have choices based on other values in that record?

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue of dependent (Cascading) comboboxes in a datasheet.
By nature,  if combobox 1 is dependent on a value from combobox 2,   it will apply the "rowsource" from the current row to all rows in the datatable

Solution:

1 In the load or designer, define the rowsource to include all rows so the datavalue behind it will always match with an option in the rowsource (otherwise you display a blank value)

ie:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.cmbProjects.RowSource = "SELECT [Projects].[ProjectPK],  [Projects].[ProjectName], [Projects].[PI_ID] FROM [Projects]  ORDER BY  [ProjectName] "
End Sub
```

2 In the dependent combobox get focus event, redefine the rowsource to be based on a value from the other combo box that the former depends on. Requery the control

```
Private Sub cmbProjects_GotFocus()
Me.cmbProjects.RowSource = "SELECT [Projects].[ProjectPK],  [Projects].[ProjectName], [Projects].[PI_ID],  [Projects].[Status] FROM [Projects]  WHERE [PI_ID] = " + CStr(cmbPIs.Value) + " ORDER BY [PI_ID], [ProjectName] "
cmbProjects.Requery
End Sub
```

3 In the dependent combobox lost focus event, redefine the rowsource to NOT be based on a value from the other combo box that the former depends on.

```
Private Sub cmbProjects_LostFocus()
Me.cmbProjects.RowSource = "SELECT [Projects].[ProjectPK],  [Projects].[ProjectName], [Projects].[PI_ID],  [Projects].[Status] FROM [Projects]  ORDER BY [PI_ID], [ProjectName] "
cmbProjects.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: This pretty much works but when I'm I've got focus in cmbProject all the other cmbProject dropdowns in the other row are blank until I select something in cmbProject and then move to the next field. When I move to the next field all the other cmbProject's get their values back though. Is there any way to stop them being blanked out?

Comment: No. See LLS answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't, but you can work around it by creating a continuous form, putting your fields in tabular layout, then adding a textbox for each combobox (if field is prodID, then I name the textbox txtprodID). Move the textbox right on top of the combobox, but a little narrower, just shy of the combo list arrow, then write code to update the textbox.