# Access subform in datasheet view changes my records when adding new

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, subform

I have created an auxiliary table to later save information in different tables easily. I made a subform to load this table. To do this, use a field that modifies a query that another field uses as a row source (which stores an ID and displays a name).
The problem is that when adding another record the name of the previous records is also modified if I change the first field.

The first record (OK)
[image: The first record (OK)]
When i add a second record whith another label
[image: When i add a second record whith another label]

```
SELECT Resina.Id_Resina, Resina.Nombre
FROM Resina
WHERE ((([Formularios]![F4_Nueva_OC]![F4_OCaux]![tipo])="Resina"));
UNION SELECT Materiales.Id_Materiales, Materiales.Descripcion
FROM Materiales
WHERE ((([Formularios]![F4_Nueva_OC]![F4_OCaux]![tipo])="Material"));
UNION
SELECT Elemento.Id_Elemento, Mueble.Nombre
FROM Mueble INNER JOIN Elemento ON Mueble.Id_Mueble = Elemento.Id_Mueble
WHERE ((([Formularios]![F4_Nueva_OC]![F4_OCaux]![tipo])="Mueble"));
UNION
SELECT Elemento.Id_Elemento, Pieza.Nombre
FROM Pieza INNER JOIN Elemento ON Pieza.Id_Pieza = Elemento.Id_Pieza
WHERE ((([Formularios]![F4_Nueva_OC]![F4_OCaux]![tipo])="Pieza"));
UNION SELECT Elemento.Id_Elemento, Accesorio.Nombre
FROM Accesorio INNER JOIN Elemento ON Accesorio.Id_Accesorio = Elemento.Id_Accesorio
WHERE ((([Formularios]![F4_Nueva_OC]![F4_OCaux]![tipo])="Accesorio"));
```

This is the query (row origin)

Comment: Possibly combobox is bound to wrong field. What is subform RecordSource? Just bind it to table, not a query.

Comment: The subform recodsource is a auxiliary table.
The idea of this subform is to load an auxiliary table (OCaux) so that the products added in the new OC form can be easily observed. Then, by VBA code, each one will be inserted in its corresponding table. The code is working correctly, what fails is the way of visualization, since when changing the category "Tipo" it affects the query that shows the column "Nombre" (but not the ID that I want to save).

Comment: Just took closer look at query. I expect what is happening is the unique ID values are replicated between tables. There would be multiple records with ID 1. Access will display the first Nombre in list with ID of 1. So when filter is applied that removes Nombre values whatever Nombre is left with ID 1 is displayed for any records where ID 1 is saved. Data structure is root of issue.

Comment: I picked ID 1 as example. This issue of course applies to all ID numbers.

Comment: What you have is a 'cascading combobox' - a combobox that is dynamically filtered by some other value on form. Cascading combobox does not work nicely on continuous or datasheet form, as you are discovering. This issue is a common topic in many forums. Issue is further compounded by your data structure which results in duplicate ID numbers. The usual workaround for continuous and datasheet forms would be more difficult to implement.

Comment: Actually, the workaround in your situation may be impossible. Usually, the filter results in records showing a blank combobox but in your case you get wrong Nombre because of duplicate IDs. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541860/using-cascading-combo-boxes-in-a-datasheet-subform